# Using open/close braces in macros to enforce pairing in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose that I have a requirement that if an operation is performed within a scope, then it must be undone in the same scope. An example of that is entering and leaving a critical section.

In order to enforce users to use paired do - undo operations, a pair of macros is defined that use open and close braces:

```
#define BEGIN \
{ \
    do_something();

#define END \
    undo_something(); \
}
```

Of course, there are ways that a "malicious" coder can trick those macros (e.g. by adding a an opening or closing brace), but generally this helps remembering that a `BEGIN` must be followed by an `END`. Moreover, if, for example, an existing `BEGIN` is commented out, the compiler will complain, indicating that the `END` must be removed also.

I have seen this is several internal projects. As I said, it does not offer 100% protection but could this practice prove harmful in any way? Is this a well-known practice?

Comment: An even amount of mistakes may go undetected.

Comment: As I said, there are many ways errors can go undetected but I am asking if this can actually be harmful in some way (i.e. produce code in an unexpected manner).

Comment: why don't you just use the names `begin()` and `end()` for `do_something` and `undo_something`? Or `Begin()` and `End()` if you want them to stand out more and your capitalization finger needs exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question you want to enforce the use of `BEGIN` / `END`.

You can do that using the infamous `goto`:

```
#define BEGIN \
do { \
    goto check_label_end; \
label_begin: \
    puts("begin"); \
} while (0);

#define END \
do { \
    puts("end"); \
    break; \
check_label_end: \
    goto label_begin; \
} while (0);
```

Then, if `BEGIN` is used without the `END` part you receive an error:

```
error: label ‘check_label_end’ used but not defined
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @ KlasLindbäck in comments, this version limits the use of `BEGIN` / `END` to once per function.

You can pass a label name in order to use several blocks:

```
#define BEGIN(op) \
do { \
    goto check_label_end_##op; \
label_begin_##op: \
    puts("begin"); \
} while (0);

#define END(op) \
do { \
    puts("end"); \
    break; \
check_label_end_##op: \
    goto label_begin_##op; \
} while (0);

BEGIN(undo)
...
END(undo)

BEGIN(something_else)
...
END(something_else)
```

Comment: Nifty. It should be noted that this limits the use of `BEGIN`/`END` to once per function.

Comment: For this to be practical you need a way to generate distinct label names for each usage of the macro in such a way that the **intended** pairs find each other. I'm not sure if that really reduces the chance to write a bug compared to useing no special technique at all.

Comment: This is a cool trick thanks! The only con I see is that the generated code will make two unnecessary jumps while in BEGIN, unless compilers optimize those out (I think they do not).

Comment: After a simple check, it looks that at least ARM gcc DOES optimize the jumps. So this is a 10/10 answer!

Answer (score 2):

For simple cases I don't see a problem, but you can construct scenarious, where this breaks your code:

```
BEGIN
...
for(...) {
    END
    ...
    BEGIN
}
...
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The sensible way to do this is not through macros, but through functions. For example:

```
typedef void task_t (void);

inline void do_critical_stuff (task_t* task)
{
  enter_critical_section();
  task();
  leave_critical_section();
}
```

Or if you are looking for something completely variable:

```
inline void do_stuff (begin_t* begin, task_t* task, end_t* end)
{
  begin();
  task();
  end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FOO(body) {\
    do_something();\
    body\
    undo_something();\
}
```

You use this macro like:

```
FOO({
    //your code here
})
```

--

Edit:

Okay, StoryTeller's example breaks my code so easily in a way I've never seen.

I guess I rarely write multiple declarations in a single line.

Comma operator and function calls never break like `a=(1,2);` or `memcpy(&a,&b,1);`

Comment: @StoryTeller switching to `__VA_ARGS__` fixes it easily though :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I wrote a lot of such code. Never have problems for my own hobby projects.

Comment: @cshu - I just linked to an example that breaks with your answer on the simplest body I could imagine. Either you uses it in a limited very fashion, or your answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any serious problem provided that `BEGIN`/`END` are used (and indented) the same way as other blocks.

The obvious caveat is that `return`/`longjmp`/`goto` breaks the pattern, but as long as all coders know this it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Example:

```
void foo() {
  ...
  BEGIN
    ...
    if (some_condition) {
      return;  // Cleanup code skipped
    }
    ...
  END
  ...
}
```

Comment: To be fair, `longjmp/goto` are very good at any pattern breaking if used carelessly.